# Retrieving relationship data in Eloquent ORM (Laravel PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm creating Laravel app and I'm retrieving data from DB with Eloquent ORM while responding with a JSON response. In this example I'm getting matches with some other relevant data by relationship (player1, matchRule...).

```
public function test() {
    $match = Match::where("state", 2)
        ->with("player1", "player2", "points", "matchRule")->first();

    return response()->json($match); // CASE A
    return response()->json((object) ["id" => $match->id]); // CASE B
    return response()->json((object) ["rule" => $match->match_rule]); // CASE C
}
```

In case A, everything's fine and all relevant data are returned. Example:

```
{
   "id": 7,
   "some_other_match_property": "something",
   ...
   "match_rule": {
      "rule_1": "something",
      "rule_2": "something",
   }

}
```

In case B, I'm getting just id of match and it also works just fine.

```
{
   "id": 7
}
```

I case C, I'm trying to get property `match_rule` but I'm getting null. Why? As you can see, it is present in the `$match` object when returning the entire match in case A.

```
{
    "rule": null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance I can see that you load your `matchRule` relationship like this ([camel case](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)):

```
$match = Match::where("state", 2)
    ->with("player1", "player2", "points", "matchRule")->first();
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

But then you are accessing the relationship like this instead ([snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)):

```
return response()->json((object) ["rule" => $match->match_rule]);
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Those are not equivalent. Try this instead:

```
return response()->json((object) ["rule" => $match->matchRule]);
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Oh yeah you're right! Thank you! But as you can see in the case A, property name in `$match` object is `match_rule` so why I can't access it by `->match_rule`?

Comment: @P.N. I think is the default behavior in Laravel to get the snake version of the relationship (function name) when gotten as an attribute. Check [this thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13614), there is mentioned that this could be disabled setting to `false` the `$snakeAttributes` property of the model: `public static $snakeAttributes = false;`. Give it a try and comeback to tell us if it worked. Have a nice day.